# Can't find VIM TagList and NERDTree commands in 'Cmder' console emulator

Tags: vim, nerdtree, cmder, taglist

I can't move to the VIM TagList window when I'm using vim in 'Cmder'  console emulator.

I'm able to use :TlistToggle, :TlistAddFiles , etc commands.. but cannot move to the taglist window using (most common) way such 'Ctrl + w'

same is with NERDTree. I'm able to start it using ':NERDTree', but how to access the NERDTree browser from 'Cmder' ?

I would really appreciate if someone can help me with this.

Comment: `<C-w>` does nothing. How about `<C-w>p` or `<C-w>w`?

Comment: Hey @romainl -- it worked. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One hack to get into the TagList window is by typing `:TlistOpen` inside vim

But, still this doesn't solve everything I'm looking for.